# Sending Play Framework File Uploads To Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, playframework

I have a Play (version 1.4) app currently hosted on Heroku that lets users create items for auction like eBay. The main process is the user fills out a form with information about the photo that is being uploaded. When the form is submitted the information is stored in a database. The photo however, I want to be stored using Amazon's S3 service.  On success, the page that creates the auction item is directed to a page that shows the image with the information that was just uploaded.

I am probably more than half way there, because when my form submits, the image is successfully being sent to the bucket I created for it using S3.  So that's good news. The bad news is, immediately upon submission, the app crashes, I get my "Oops!" error page, and when I check my database, none of the information was saved. The method responsible for creating the new auction item, doCreateItem(), the process I just described, where I am able to send the photo to AWS, but the app crashes not saving the data to the database, that method, looks like this:

```
public static void doCreateItem(@Valid AuctionItem item){
    if (validation.hasErrors()){
    params.flash();
    validation.keep();
    createAuctionItem();    
    }
    // item.photo = new S3Blob();
    // item.photo.set(new FileInputStream(item.photo), MimeTypes.getContentType(item.photo.getName()));
    item.createdBy = Authenticate.getLoggedInUser();
    item.save();
    show(item.id);
}
```

https://github.com/cmazzochi81/java-play-app/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java

And the stack trace, looks like this: 
[image]

In the stack trace when it refers to this error:

```
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 43)
```

Line 43 in my code is the following line where the method is trying to save the data to the database:

```
item.save();
```

Now when I uncomment out the two lines in the doCreateMethod()

```
item.photo = new S3Blob();
item.photo.set(new FileInputStream(item.photo)
```

When I do that, I'm not even able to push my app to Heroku. The error in the console says the constructor FileInputStream(S3Blob), is undefined:

[image]
I am trying to do the exact same thing James Ward does in this article: 
https://www.jamesward.com/2011/09/13/sending-play-framework-file-uploads-to-amazon-s3

The GitHub repo for my project can be found here: 
https://github.com/cmazzochi81/java-play-app

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I have worked extremely hard on this project, and it is this close to being done.

Thank you in advance, 
CM